# Apex Charts line color not set correctly

Tags: apexcharts

When creating a chart in 'react-apexcharts' it is my understanding that colors should be inherited. However, when creating multiple series with a colors array the legend is set but not the line color.

Codepen demonstration here.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-charts-demo-325oh

Answer (score 9):

Instead of color names, try hex color codes.

```
    options: {
      colors: ["#008000", "#FF0000"]
    }
```

Color names are supported at some places in ApexCharts, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

use the fill property or colors under options.

Link: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/#colors

code snippet example:

```
const options = {
    colors: ["#E27483", "#F8C300"]
}
```